# VW Eos - Is this normal kind of rust on the underside (control arm) of a 14 year old car?

Tags: maintenance, car, rust, corrosion

My first post here.

I'm looking to get a 14 year old VW Eos, but I noticed some rust going on in this underside bar shown in the picture. Everywhere else is fine.
There are some circular holes in the bar, what are those for?
I have also noticed some flaking off of surfaces. Is this going to be a structural issue?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Structurally, no, there is no issue here ... *yet*. The holes are there from the factory for some reason. Nature (ie: rust) does not create perfect holes. The rust you have on there is primarily surface rust. If you do something about it now, it will stop and you'll never have to worry about it.

The rust occurs in areas which use salt for road treatment during the winter time or possibly in areas which are high in humidity.

The best way to "fix" this is to tear it apart and put a rust converter on it, like POR-15, Rustoleum, or even Eastwood makes one, too. The reason I suggest to take it apart is so you can get all the nooks and crannies. If this is not an option for you, just applying it where you can is a good option as it will convert the rust over to an inert compound which basically kills the rust from continuing to deteriorate the metal.

On the other hand, if you don't feel like this is something you can take care of on your own. you can leave it alone and it will probably last another 8-10 years before it actually becomes a real problem.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the name of that bar and what's it used for?

Comment: I believe the part you are asking about is called a lower control arm.